# How do I simplify this query?

Tags: sql, simplify

so my main goal with this query is to select all departments and employees under a manager named Mario Souza.

```
SELECT d.deptname,e.name FROM employee e JOIN department d ON e.dept = d.deptnum WHERE idmanager IN(
SELECT id FROM employee WHERE name = 'Mario Souza' 
) AND manager IN(
SELECT id FROM employee WHERE name = 'Mario Souza' 
)
```

And it's working, but is there a way I could store the first IN result so I could use it later after the AND operator?

Comment: 1) So, an employee can have a manager different from the manager of the department it works for? 2) If an employee has a manager different than Mario, but works on a department whose manager is Mario should he be displayed?

Comment: It's actually an exercise and the question doesn't specify what you just asked, but I'll just solve it both ways. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` to match on multiple columns.

```
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM employee AS manager
    WHERE manager.name = 'Mario Souza'
    AND manager.id = e.idmanager
    AND manager.id = d.manager
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked great and I didn't know about the EXIST condition, so thanks again for showing it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a JOIN with employee table. Simply put both manager and idmanager in ON clause.

Comment: Your answer also worked for this case and was simpler. Thanks.